# Do Metro apps work on Windows XP or Windows 7?

Tags: c#

I'm building a desktop program using Visual Studio and noticed that they added support for Metro apps. Do these work on XP and 7 as well (desktop applications)?

Answer (score 3):

No.

Metro-style applications are completely new to Windows 8.

Comment: really? I thought "Metro" was just a term to describe the new fancy WPF-based .NET application framework...

Comment: Metro apps run in a different windows environment (windows RT)

Comment: @KitRoed: Nope.  Metro has nothing to do with WPF.

Comment: @Team-JoKi so what is GitHub for Windows built on? Seems like I heard it referred to as a "Metro" app...

Comment: @KitRoed GitHub for Windows is an ordinary WPF app that follows Metro design principles.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for the clarification! (see, I'm learning something!)

Answer (score 0):

To make Windows 8-style applications with multi-touch support for Windows 7 (and maybe for XP, I am not sure), it is possible to use Microsoft Surface SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727815.aspx But this SDK is just addition to .NET Framework. When program written with Surface SDK is executed in Windows 8, it runs inside the Desktop subsystem, and not in native Windows 8 environment. Real Metro applications run only in Windows 8.